# Is it possible to get the delivery timestamp of a push notification?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

If an app isn't running when a push arrives, and is later launched via the resulting notification in the notification center, is there any way the app can find out what time the push arrived without explicitly putting a timestamp when the server sent it as part of the payload (which wouldn't actually be the same as the arrival time, but close enough most of the time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to documentation

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

userInfo has predefined **aps** NSDictionary (containing alert, badge and sound values) and custom key/values. So, there is no additional key for original notification arrival time.